# Is Array<Bool> optimized for space?

Tags: arrays, swift, boolean

Since a `Bool` is typically represented as an entire byte, I wanted to know whether or not Swift's compiler optimizes a `[Bool]` so that each element is a single bit. Swift is still a fairly young language, so I figured there might still be a chance that this optimization hasn't occurred yet.

Comment: Don't know what the downvote was for, seems like a legitimate question to me.  Have an upvote.

Comment: Was really scratching my head over that one too. One vote to close for being "primarily opinion-based." Huh. Pretty sure asking about compiler specs are as objective as questions get.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but while it is perfectly reasonable to ask whether the compiler can do bit-packing of array of `Bool`, this question quickly drifts into the realm of speculation and opinion when it goes on to infer that the lack of said feature is because it is an immature language with the concomitant assumption that some bit-packing will be included in the future releases.

Comment: Swift's young age is actually the reason that I am asking the question. I could only speculate on why if I knew whether such an optimization exists, which I do not. I was hoping someone with better debugging skills than myself would be able to perform some lldb magic to discover the answer.

Comment: I understand, and if you left it at "does it bit pack" (and shown us your research), you might not have received down votes. But you're also assuming this feature will be added (debatable) and are therefore implicitly inviting people to speculate if and when this capability will be added (opinion). Regardless, don't worry about down-votes, because if the broader community thinks this is a good question, you'll get offsetting up-votes. If you really want to engage in further discussion as to whether this is a good or bad question, move that discussion to http://meta.stackoverflow.com, not here.

Comment: This is a classic moment for one language to learn from another. C++'s vector<bool> is space optimized and it's widely considered to have been a huge mistake. There are articles that will go into more detail, but basically it's not always what you want anyway, and it can break generic code in surprising ways. An Array<T> should return references to T (or Swift equivalent) when accessed, but since 1 bit variables don't exist, this is impossible for bit packed booleans, so now you have proxies... Not a good idea.